# Default DNS server as assigned by SonicWall 3500, how to change which DNS server is used

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, sonicwall

I have a SonicWall 3500 that we use as a DHCP server.

We've recently switched our internal DNS server from an old Mac Tiger Server to our new Server 2008 box. I've migrated the zones over, I've flushed my dns cache and manually set the new one as the DNS server, tested it, and all local domain names are resolving correctly. So now I want to make it a global change. All our client computers are set up to receive DNS information from the DHCP server automatically. When I changed my computer back to this option, it's still assigning the old DNS server. Where in the SonicWall configuration do you set which DNS server it is to assign with the DHCP leases?
Initially I thought it was under Network > DNS, but that appears to just be the DNS configuration for the Sonicwall itself, and not what it's issuing with DHCP. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. In the DHCP options we've specified three separate IP address ranges to be used for leases in dynamic assignment, and those three objects had the DNS information manually entered. Fixed.